# Why are BufferedReader and Scanner not identifying line breaks?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputstream, bufferedreader, line-breaks

I have a program which is reading data from an external testing instrument via a serial port. It uses [jSerialComm](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/) to communicate over the serial port. The data is line-delimited, so I decided to use a BufferedReader to read it line-by-line. Unfortunately, when the [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) method is called, it blocks until the read times out. I tried using Scanner and I had the same issue with [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) blocking.

```
SerialPort port = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM4");
port.openPort();
port.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING, 10000, 0);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(port.getInputStream()));
while(true) {
    // This line blocks forever
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
}
```

I thought that maybe a special character was being used for line-breaks, so I read the raw bytes from the stream and printed them to console:

```
int byteRead;
InputStream stream = port.getInputStream();
while ((byteRead = stream.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.write(byteRead);
    System.out.print(byteRead);
}
```

This is a sample of the output:

```
10M77E69A65N78 32=61 32654957.46654654 32H72R82351048N78
13
10S83T84D68 32D68E69V86 32=61 32755.46553553 32H72R82351048N78
13
10L76O79W87E69S83T84 32=61 32250654.46351048 32H72R82351048N78
13
```

You can clearly see that the [ASCII character 13](https://www.asciitable.com/) (carriage return) is being used as the line delimiter, which in Java is represented as `\r`. The JavaDoc for [`BufferedReader#readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) says:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
> of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
> followed immediately by a linefeed.

This leaves me very confused, as the BufferedReader should work in this scenario but does not. I drafted a proof-of-concept for a line-delimited reader which breaks on newline characters `\n` (or ASCII 10) and carriage returns `\r` (ASCII 13), and trims leading and trailing `\r` and `\n` characters:

```
public class ScaleReader {

    private InputStream scaleInputStream;

    public ScaleReader(InputStream scaleInputStream) {
        this.scaleInputStream = scaleInputStream;
    }

    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        int charByte = scaleInputStream.read();
        while (charByte != -1 && charByte == 13 || charByte == 10)
            charByte = scaleInputStream.read();

        if (charByte == -1)
            return null;

        builder.append((char) charByte);
        
        while (true) {
            charByte = scaleInputStream.read();
            if (charByte == -1 || charByte == 13 || charByte == 10)
                break;

            builder.append((char) charByte);
        }

        return builder.length() == 0 ? null : builder.toString();
    }

}
```

This code works as expected and returns the correct data for each call to `readLine()`. I cannot understand why BufferedReader is not working in this scenario, when it is clearly supposed to recognize carriage returns as line terminators.

Is there an explanation?

Comment: You're creating an `InputStreamReader` without specifying the character encoding - which means the platform default will be used. What is your platform default encoding? Have you tried specifying one explicitly?

Comment: You might try reading individual characters from your `BufferedReader` and printing *those* out - that's likely to help identify the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried `BufferedReader#read` to read a single byte and the method never returns.

Comment: That's odd. But okay, next try without the BufferedReader, just using InputStreamReader. (Note that you're not reading *bytes* from a reader, but *characters* - you need to differentiate between the two.)

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for making that distinction for me. I will remember that in the future. I tried using just the InputStreamReader, but to no avail.